# UITest: Check if text with prefix exists

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

While doing a UI test, I can test that a text exists like this:

```
XCTAssertTrue(tablesQuery.staticTexts["Born: May 7, 1944"].exists)
```

But, **how do I test if a text exist, if I only know the prefix?**

I would like to do something like:

```
XCTAssertTrue(tablesQuery.staticTextWithPrefix["Born: "].exists)
```

or even better:

```
XCTAssertTrue(tablesQuery.staticTextWithRegex["Born: .+"].exists)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use predicates to find elements by prefixes. For example:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'Born: '")
let element = app.staticTexts.elementMatchingPredicate(predicate)
XCTAssert(element.exists)
```

Note that this could fail if more than one element matches the predicate. More information can be found in a blog post, a [Cheat Sheet for UI Testing](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#picker-with-multiple-wheels).